# My build doesn't appear on iTunes Connect

Tags: build, app-store-connect, ipa

```
{
    "ipa_upload":"success",
    "ipa_uploader":"Application Loader 3.0",
    "builder": "XCode 8.0(8A218a)"
}
```

In itunes connect's, Activity -> All Builds, my build doesn't appear. Waited 12 hours, nothing.

You guys know what can I do?

EDIT:

Got it. Apple took my BUILD and said "OK" but then sent me an email. since I don't have access to that email I didn't know... poor design from Apple on this specific piece of software, it should tell you right off the bat, while uploading, that there's a problem with your build.

Comment: check your email for email from apple 'iTunes Connect: Version XXX for XXX has completed processing.'. Once you receive an email you can submit app for approval. Another option is try to submit again from xcode to see if there were submission issue. It shoudn't take 12 hours to get app visibile in builds

Comment: yeah I know, it always shows up right after "Upload OK" from Application Loader, but not this time. Cannot upload again 'cause I get "Binary Already Exists" error. Already reported the problem to Apple. I'll see what they've to say

Comment: I am having the same issue.  I have uploaded two builds and neither are showing up.  I even tried with the second build upload a different app version, but neither are visible inside the apps "prepare for submission"

Answer (score 1):

It seems Apple has changed their process some recently.  I uploaded version 3.13 and in the past, you would be able to press the + button and see the build in still being processes.  However, today there will be NO + button on the prepare for submission page until the build is finished processing.